# Casting 1 to decimal returns 0.9999 instead of 1.0000 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, casting

When casting 1 to decimal in MySQL, I was expecting `1.0000`, but instead the output is `0.9999`.

What exactly is happening here?

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(4,4))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Because you specified that there will be four digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @tkausl not a duplicate, that question has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: Look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html. With `Decimal(4,4)` the range of values would be `-0.9999 to 0.9999`

Comment: Shouldn't this be an overflow? I just tested on SQL Server and got that as my error.

Comment: @1000111 ah that makes sense, 4 precision and 4 scale.  So to get 1.0000 I need 5,4.

Comment: Exactly! `Decimal(x,y)` will reserve `(x minus y)` digits before the decimal and `y` digits after the decimal.

Comment: @shawnt00 this is for MySQL, not SQL.

Comment: Postgres `ERROR: numeric field overflow Detail: A field with precision 4, scale 4 must round to an absolute value less than 1.`

Comment: Seems to work on SQLite though.

Comment: SQL and SQLite are not MySQL.  They are different databases all together, so their implementation of the query syntax will vary.

Comment: `ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`

Comment: @ZackTeater I'm well aware of the various platforms. This is probably a departure from SQL standards which is why I was going to the trouble of investigating all that. There could be a setting that impacts the way values are rounded though and I don't know enough about MySQL to say for sure.

Comment: @tkausl This doesn't really even involve floating point math so it's not a duplicate of that question at least. Of course the concept of floating point certainly applies to it very much when using those types.

Comment: @shawnt00 retracted my close vote. Looked like floating point math on the first glance though.

Comment: @shawnt00 MySQL does throw a warning with this query `1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)`. Some broken clients seem to ignore warnings (What could possibly go wrong when they do that? I digress.) but `SHOW WARNINGS;` would reveal the explanation; with `@@SQL_MODE` including `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, MySQL, MySQL should not allow this value to actually be inserted into a table.

Comment: `1.0000` requires `DECIMAL(5, 4)`, not `DECIMAL(4, 4)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

out of range

For example, DECIMAL(5,2) store any value with five digits and two decimals, its range from -999.99 to 999.99.

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(5,4)) -> 1.0000
SELECT CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(4,3)) -> 1.000
SELECT CAST(0.0001 AS DECIMAL(4,4)) -> 0.0001
SELECT CAST(0.00001 AS DECIMAL(4,4)) -> 0.0000
SELECT CAST(12345 AS DECIMAL(5,4)) -> 9.9999
```

More info:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html

Answer (score 5):

MySQL is clipping the converted value to the largest one that will fit in the target type. A `decimal(4, 4)` doesn't allot any significant digits to the left of the decimal place.

This cast does not cause overflow only when the server is not running a strict mode as described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html).

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to convert an integer (In your case its value is 1) into Decimal number **DECIMAL(n,m)** that have **precision n i.e. total number of digit** (n=4 in your case) and **scale as m i.e. number of digits after decimal** (m=4 in your case)

So In your case **decimal number will range from (-0.9999 to 0.9999)**

And so when you try to **convert any integer > 0** it will be **converted as 0.9999**(Maximum possible value)

and when you try to **convert any integer < 0** it will be **converted as -0.9999**(minimum possible value)

this kind of conversion will cause an error if server run in strict mode.

Comment: `m` is not the scale, it is the number of decimal places.